# SAPUI5 hybrid app - Add custom icon to push notification

Tags: sapui5, hybrid-mobile-app, sap-mobile-services

Is it possible to add a custom icon to push notification when using `kapsel-plugin-push`?

I have read blogs, like:

- [Getting Started With Kapsel - Part 4 - Push](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/10/30/getting-started-kapsel-part-4-pushsp13/)
- [How to config and consume Push Notification from SAP Mobile Services](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/06/09/how-to-enable-push-notifications-%EF%BC%88part2/)

and tried to add `icon` property to `gcmNotification`. Icon appeared in notification, but after that, there was no sound when notification arrives (I have fixed that issue by adding `sound` property). Also notification payload is not applicable (`data` in notification was not processed by application).

If I remove `gcmNotification`, notification sound is working as well as `data` in notification payload.

---

I am sending requests to SCPms via Postman. Here is an example of

```json
{
  "alert": "Test alert",
  "data": "{\"TSLASTTEMP\":\"Sat Mar 31 2018 18:09:02\",\"LASTTEMP\":\"35\", \"NUMBER\": \"1231244234/2a\"}",
  "sound": "default",
  "gcmNotification": {
    "icon": "sap",
    "color": "blue"
  }
}
```